# Is there any way to update list of map in firestore?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to update only timestamp if `userId` available? I used `FieldValue.arrayUnion([{map}])`, but when change timestamp, adding a new item to the list.

```
  return _db.collection('requirement').document(docId).updateData({
    'chatData':[{
      'userId':userId,
      'timestamp':Timestamp.now()
    }],
  });
```

**The Reason I used:** I want to sort `requirement` data with `userId.timestamp`. that's why, I decided to use the list of map

Answer (score 2):

You cannot selectivly update one element in an array. If your requirements allow it a workaround is to transform your array into a map.